# Including results in GROUP BY when the count is zero for one of the groups

Tags: mysql

I am successfully running the following query, but need to all status's represented in the returned results, even if there are zero status's of one kind or another:

```
SELECT status,
sum(case when status = 'New' then 1 else 0 end),
sum(case when status = '1 Attempt' then 1 else 0 end),
sum(case when status = '2 Attempts' then 1 else 0 end),
sum(case when status = '3 Attempts' then 1 else 0 end),
sum(case when status = 'Connected' then 1 else 0 end),
sum(case when status = 'Follow Up' then 1 else 0 end),
sum(case when status = 'Referred' then 1 else 0 end)
FROM Contact
GROUP BY status
HAVING status NOT IN('Invalid', 'Archived')
ORDER BY FIELD (status, 'New', '1 Attempt', '2 Attempts', '3 Attempts', 'Connected',    'Follow Up', 'Referred')
```

Presently, I get these results if there is 1 "New" status and 1 "Connected" status:

```
0          1 2 3 4 5 6 7
New        1 0 0 0 0 0 0
Connected  0 0 0 0 1 0 0
```

What I want is in the case above is:

```
0          1 2 3 4 5 6 7
New        1 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 Attempt  0 0 0 0 0 0 0
2 Attempts 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
3 Attempts 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
Connected  0 0 0 0 1 0 0
etc...
```

Any help to do this would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Simply removing the GROUP BY does not work? You should get one single result row, having one column per type of status.

Comment: Do you have each of those statuses in your table?  Your query will only return those statuses that exist in your table.

Comment: How can you `GROUP BY` a status that is non-existent? It sounds like you need a table to define the available statuses and need to LEFT JOIN from that table to this.

Comment: Thanks for this input... Tried removing GROUP BY, did not work as needed. I see that I cannot group by non-existent statuses... will they kiks73 solution below. Just need to change code to get desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT p.status as `0`,
sum(case when c.status = 'New' then 1 else 0 end) as `1`,
sum(case when c.status = '1 Attempt' then 1 else 0 end) `2`,
sum(case when c.status = '2 Attempts' then 1 else 0 end) `3`,
sum(case when c.status = '3 Attempts' then 1 else 0 end) `4`,
sum(case when c.status = 'Connected' then 1 else 0 end) `5`,
sum(case when c.status = 'Follow Up' then 1 else 0 end) `6`,
sum(case when c.status = 'Referred' then 1 else 0 end) `7`
FROM (
  SELECT 'New' Status
  Union SELECT '1 Attempt' Status
  Union SELECT '2 Attempts' Status
  Union SELECT '3 Attempts' Status
  Union SELECT 'Connected' Status
  Union SELECT 'Follow Up' Status
  Union SELECT 'Referred' Status
) p
LEFT JOIN Contact c ON p.status = c.status
GROUP BY p.status
HAVING status NOT IN('Invalid', 'Archived')
ORDER BY FIELD (p.status, 'New', '1 Attempt', '2 Attempts', '3 Attempts', 'Connected',    'Follow Up', 'Referred')
```

Demo --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9500f/1

Comment: That is exactly what I need. Thanks Kordiko!

Answer (score 0):

```
select status, sum(case when status ='New' then 1 else 0) as '1',0 as '2', 0 as '3', 0 as '4', ..., from Contact group by status 

Union

select status, 0 as '1' , sum(case when status ='1 Attempt' then 1 else 0) as '1',0 as '2', 0 as '3', 0 as '4', ..., from Contact group by status

Union


...
```

Answer (score 0):

This will not be exactly the format you require, but it will fetch the required data in one row, with each sum as a column:

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'New' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_new,
SUM(CASE WHEN status = '1 Attempt' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_1_attempt,
SUM(CASE WHEN status = '2 Attempts' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_2_attempts,
SUM(CASE WHEN status = '3 Attempts' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_3_attempts,
SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'Connected' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_connected,
SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'Follow Up' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_follow_up,
SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'Referred' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_referred
FROM Contact
```

Comment: Thanks Wolfgang. This works to get the results, but for the charting I am doing (dojo) it needs to be in the format originally posted.